# uikit - modal window on the fly via javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, uikit

I switched my website from bootstrap to uikit.

In bootstrap I could create modal windows on the fly via javascript. I used this example:

https://gist.github.com/saigach/4ef5d8ad5f6ddd6dc64afc302caa3552

That was fine, but I am not able to create a uikit modal on the fly...

```
var popupTemplate = 
'<div id="modal-example" uk-modal>' + 
'    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">' + 
'        <h2 class="uk-modal-title">Headline</h2>' + 
'        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>' + 
'        <p class="uk-text-right">' + 
'            <button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-modal-close" type="button">Cancel</button>' + 
'            <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary" type="button">Save</button>' + 
'        </p>' + 
'    </div>' + 
'</div>' + 

$(popupTemplate).modal();
```

I also tried

```
$(popupTemplate).toggle();
```

Nothing happens. Has anybody an idea how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(popupTemplate).modal(); is not going to work.
```

You need to do :

```
$("#someDivId").html(popupTemplate);
```

then

```
$("#modal-example").modal();
```